# Replace all "\/" from string

Tags: javascript

So the goal is theoretically very simple. I want to replace every `\/` from a string.

```js
const a = '/\/awd\//g'.replaceAll('\\/', '');
const b = '/\/awd\//g'.replace(/\\\//g, '');
const c = '/\/awd\//g'.replace('/\\/g', '');
const d = '/\/awd\//g'.replace('/\\//', '');

console.log(a, b, c, d);
```

Result should be: `/awd/g`;

Is there even a way to do it? I dont want to use map or iterate over every letter. I just want to use replace function with regex or substring. And I dont know how many `\/` are there inside string. Thank you

Also there can be "i" or "g" or "m" or "igm" or "ig" or "im" or "mi" and so on instead of that "g" at the end.

Comment: First problem is ... none of your string var \/ in them

Comment: can you explain better what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Giuppox I want to remove every `\/` from my string.

Comment: you have no strings with \/ in them - `"/\\/awd\\//g"` - then you will ... then use `.replace(/\\\//g, '');` or `.replaceAll('\\/', '');` .... escapes and regex can be confisung

Comment: @JaromandaX Theres two of them

Comment: Is `/\/awd\//g` the actual input? Remember that \ is a special character, so `'/\/awd\//g'` is actually `//awd//g`, ie. there are no instances of `\/` in your example.

Comment: @Patrickkx no, there are NONE `console.log(a.charCodeAt(1))` - or `console.log(a.length)` ... it's 8 not 10 right  or remove the .replace and console.log them ... see ... no \

Comment: @Patrickkx just do `console.log(a, b, c, d)` and find out there's no single `\/`.

Answer (score 2):

First issue is, your strings have no `\` in them

Second issue is you need to make the search string include a `\` as well

Third issue is, you attempt to use regex but use a string instead

So .. to first *create* a string with `\/` in it, you have to use `\\/`

then you need to use `"\\/"` to search for it, and use replaceAll to replace them

or, using regex, you need to escape both the \ and the / ... and not use a string for the regex - i.e. the search should be

```
/\\\//g

/        begin regular expression
 \       escape the next character
  \      literal \
   \     escape the next character
    /    literal /
     /   end regex expression
      g  global flag
```

Which will replace all `\/`

You can of course use "new RegExp(str, flags)" too

```
new Regex('\\\\/', 'g');
```

I'll let you figure out why there's 4 \ in that!

```js
const a = '/\/awd\//g';
const b = '/\\/awd\\//g';
const c = b.replace(/\\\//g, '');
const d = b.replaceAll('\\/', '');
const e = b.replaceAll(new RegExp('\\\\/', 'g'), '');

console.log(a.includes('\\'));
console.log(b.includes('\\'));
console.log(a.split('').join(' '));
console.log(b.split('').join(' '));
console.log(c)
console.log(d)
console.log(e)
```

Comment: this is a really well done answer @Patrickkx should really accept it

Answer (score -2):

Simply split by the char sequenz you want and join an empty string

```js
var a = '/\/awd\//g'.split("\/").join("")
console.log(a);  // -> awdg
```

Comment: This is just removing *all* instances of the letter '/'. It doesn't do what the OP asks for. In fact, it will leave the back slash in all instances of '\/'